# Syntax for using variable in the view of a rails application for active record query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, variables, activerecord

I've been looking for a way to properly do this for a couple of days now and haven't been able to find any posts or information yet as to how it should be done. Basically, I've got this code in one of my views:

```
<p>
  Solo Payout Age <%= i %>:
  <%= @product.solo_payout_factor_age_THIS SPOT SHOULD BE THE VALUE OF "i" %>
</p>
```

The variable "i" was declared earlier and is working just fine in the line above the active record query. I need that value to be part of the active record query too, though, and haven't been able to successfully get it to run.

I've tried all sorts of combinations of the "#{i}" method to insert the variable, but no luck.

Thanks in advance for any assistance with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p>
  Solo Payout Age <%= i %>:
  <%= @product.send("solo_payout_factor_age_#{i}")%>
</p>
```

Comment: You are a wizard - that absolutely worked; thanks for the super quick response! Apparently, I have to wait 9 minutes before I can mark this as a correct answer but I'll check back and do so then. I'll have to read up on the "send" method since I've never used that before.